# Glassy Sliding window

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

when i click a item in list view, it shows the content in sliding window which is comes from bottom of the screen.

I got this. But the problem is that contents in behind of sliding window is not visible.

I want sliding window is looking like a glassy which shows it's content as well as background content.

This image explains you everything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with this... `<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android colours can have a transparency level, so you just build the color with the amount of transparency you want and put as the background of the layout.

so you put that in your color.xml

```
<color name="trans_backg">#AARRGGBB</color>
```

just replacing:

- AA => how much transparency you want (called Alpha)
- RR => how much Red
- GG => how much Green
- BB => how much Blue

remember that those are hexadecimal values varying from 00 to FF